# How to get all the JSON values for the same keys iterated number of times using groovy?

Tags: json, groovy

```
def json = '{"book": [{"id": "01","language": "Java","edition": "third","author": "Herbert Schildt"},{"id": "07","language": "C++","edition": "second","author": "E.Balagurusamy"}]}'
```

Using Groovy code, how to get the "id" values printed for "book" array?

Output:

```
[01, 07]
```

Comment: this should work: `book*.id`

Comment: Coul you please explain with code? I have tried this one,. I am getting error as, No such property book. def idValue = json.book*.id
 log.info idValue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the working example using your input JSON.

```
import groovy.json.*
def json = '''{"book": [
                         {"id": "01","language": "Java","edition": "third","author": "Herbert Schildt"},
                         {"id": "07","language": "C++","edition": "second","author": "E.Balagurusamy"}
                       ]
              }'''
def jsonObj = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
println jsonObj.book.id // This will return the list of all values of matching key.
```

Demo here on groovy console : https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5178866532352000